# Make 'volume up' from 'mute' go to volume step one not previous volume on Macbook Pro

Tags: macos, audio, macbook-pro, mute

Currently, on my Macbook Pro (OSX 10.6.5), I will often use the 'mute' button to turn the volume off, for example if I'm working at night. I may then watch a video or something, and decide to have the volume on very quietly. So I press the 'volume up' key—but instead of going to volume level one (the logical 'volume step up' from mute), the volume jumps to whatever mega-decibels I was blasting out before I muted in the first place.

Is there a way to change the behavior of this? Ideally the 'mute' button would be changed to actually turn the volume to zero, rather than just muting. (And re-pressing mute would turn the volume back up to the original).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. Use [what I describe here](https://superuser.com/questions/224264/how-do-i-control-the-system-volume-on-os-x-with-a-keyboard-without-media-controls/224382#224382) as a workaround. Assign keyboard shortcuts on the F-keys to these scripts, and combine with [FunctionFlip](http://kevingessner.com/software/functionflip/) to get "regular function key" behavior.

---

By pressing shift while changing volume, you can suppress the volume indicator sounds. Maybe that's a workaround for pressing mute for you?

Comment: Thanks, this looks like the right way to do it. When I have time I'll give this a go. I'll try something like assigning F10 to an applescript that sets volume to 0.