# OSX Remap decrease volume key

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, remapping

I recently managed to spill some tea on my Apple keyboard. After letting it dry out, the only damage done was the loss of the F11 / decrease volume key.

While certainly cheaper than losing the whole thing, it is pretty annoying to be able to increase volume with the key, and having to use the mouse to decrease it.

Any way to remap the decrease volume function to, say, cmd + F12?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/42239

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/index.html.en).

1. Save a file like this as [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en)

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <root>
     <item>
       <name>Control-F12 to F11</name>
       <identifier>6E789935-7B50-45F5-8970-D2C6EFFEA397</identifier>
       <autogen>--ConsumerToConsumer-- ConsumerKeyCode::VOLUME_UP, VK_CONTROL, ConsumerKeyCode::VOLUME_DOWN</autogen>
       <autogen>--ConsumerToConsumer-- ConsumerKeyCode::VOLUME_UP, VK_CONTROL, VK_OPTION, VK_SHIFT, ConsumerKeyCode::VOLUME_DOWN, VK_OPTION, VK_SHIFT</autogen>
     </item>
   </root>
   ```
2. Press the Reload XML button and enable the remapping in the first tab

Comment: Ah, that's even better. I simply set the volume down/up keys to F5 and F6 respectively. Nice to get some insight into how to customize it even more though, thanks!