# How can I remap the Eject key to another in OS X?

Tags: macos, keyboard, macbook-pro, remapping

I would like to remap the <kbd>⏏</kbd> (Eject) key to <kbd>Volume Up</kbd>.

I already have KeyRemap4MacBook and need the appropriate `private.xml` file.

Answer (score 1):

Save this as [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<item>
    <name>eject to volume up</name>
    <identifier>eject_to_volume_up</identifier>
    <autogen>--ConsumerToConsumer-- ConsumerKeyCode::EJECT, ModifierFlag::NONE, ConsumerKeyCode::VOLUME_UP</autogen>
    <autogen>--ConsumerToConsumer-- ConsumerKeyCode::EJECT, VK_OPTION, VK_SHIFT, ConsumerKeyCode::VOLUME_UP, VK_OPTION, VK_SHIFT</autogen>
    <autogen>--ConsumerToConsumer-- ConsumerKeyCode::EJECT, VK_OPTION, ConsumerKeyCode::VOLUME_UP, VK_OPTION</autogen>
</item>
</root>
```

After that, press the reload XML button in the first tab and select the checkbox at the top of the list.

You can remove the delay with [NoEjectDelay](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/noejectdelay.html.en). There's no preference pane for it, but it just removes the delay after you install it and restart.

- [Another question about remapping volume keys](https://superuser.com/questions/460942/osx-remap-decrease-volume-key/461127#461127)
- [An old version of checkbox.xml that includes all predefined remappings](https://github.com/benburkert/dvorax0r/blob/master/files/prefpane/checkbox.xml)