# OSX control volume with keyboard

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, applescript

I'd like these keybindings:

```
Cmd+PageUp = volumeUp
Cmd+PageDown = volumeDown
```

I followed [these instructions](https://superuser.com/questions/224264/how-do-i-control-the-system-volume-on-os-x-with-a-keyboard-without-media-control):

creating AppleScript worked fine, but it is impossible to set Cmd+PageUp shortcut in SystemPreferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Services.

[image: script]
[image: settings]

Is it possible to run an AppleScript from `~Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBindings.dict`?

Answer (score 1):

This is very doable. The key is to create a service from your AppleScript using Automator.

1. Launch Automator and select File, New and then choose **Service**.
2. Set the service to receive *"no input"* from *"any application"*.
3. From the Actions, select **Run AppleScript** and drag that into the work area on the right.
4. Copy/paste your script into the editor
5. Save the service with an appropriate name.
6. Launch System Preferences, Keyboard and the service name you used will be available.
7. Set your shortcut as desired.

The only other method may be to use Automator to create a service that runs a bash script that would call `ossascript your_script`.  I'm not sure how you'd call the `.dict` file to get what you want accomplished.

Answer (score 0):

There is often a noticeable delay before a service (or an AppleScript script that is not ran as a service) is ran, and the keyboard shortcuts for services are not available in applications that do not have a services menu. A better option is to use a [private.xml](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/xml.html.en) like this with Karabiner:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>custom</name>
    <identifier>custom</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::PAGEUP, VK_COMMAND, ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::VK_CONSUMERKEY_VOLUME_UP</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::PAGEDOWN, VK_COMMAND, ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::VK_CONSUMERKEY_VOLUME_DOWN</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

Without `, ModifierFlag::NONE` for example the first `autogen` entry would also change option + command + page up to option + volume up.

To change volume in increments of a quarter bar, add `, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L | ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L` before `</autogen>`.

This maps the right option key to an extra modifier key when held and to F19 when pressed, and for example makes pressing the key pad 0 key while holding the extra modifier key increase volume:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>custom</name>
    <identifier>custom</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyOverlaidModifier__ KeyCode::OPTION_R, KeyCode::VK_MODIFIER_EXTRA1, KeyCode::F19</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_1, ModifierFlag::EXTRA1, KeyCode::VK_CONSUMERKEY_BRIGHTNESS_DOWN</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_2, ModifierFlag::EXTRA1, KeyCode::VK_CONSUMERKEY_BRIGHTNESS_UP</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_6, ModifierFlag::EXTRA1, KeyCode::VK_CONSUMERKEY_MUSIC_PREV</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_7, ModifierFlag::EXTRA1, KeyCode::VK_CONSUMERKEY_MUSIC_PLAY</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_8, ModifierFlag::EXTRA1, KeyCode::VK_CONSUMERKEY_MUSIC_NEXT</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_9, ModifierFlag::EXTRA1, KeyCode::VK_CONSUMERKEY_VOLUME_DOWN, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L | ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_0, ModifierFlag::EXTRA1, KeyCode::VK_CONSUMERKEY_VOLUME_UP, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L | ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```